# Should I capitalize 'the'?

Tags: definite-article, capitalization

I want to ask you a question about capitalization. I would like you to have a look at the following sentence:

> I love listening to the Joe Rogan Experience podcast.

Do I have to capitalize 'the' in the above sentence or should I keep it as a small letter.

Answer (score 2):

If the word "the" isn't part of the name of the show, it's an easy decision - keep it lower-case.

If the word "the" is part of the name of the show, it's more difficult.  This is a question of style, about which conventions vary and different people have different preferences.

In the UK, there is a newspaper called The Times.  The word "The" is part of its name.  When the Guardian and the Economist refer an article in the Times, they write:

> an article in the Times

When the Times and the Telegraph refer to an article in the Times, they write:

> an article in The Times

...although the Times writes *The Times* in italics, and the Telegraph doesn't.  The Economist writes the word *Times* in italics (but not the definite article).  The Guardian doesn't italicise either of them.

Comment: Might make it clearer that the *Times* (without the article) is an American magazine. Why not check what is the full name of the podcast. Is it "The Joe Rogan..." or "Joe Rogan..."

Comment: @Mari-LouA The Times is the name of a newspaper published in London.

Comment: Oops. Read too hastily. It looked like you were comparing "The Times" with "Times"  magazine

Comment: Wikipedia calls it "The Joe Rogan Experience" with a capital.  The show's website calls it the same thing (in all-caps), but this does not tell us the show's preferred capitalisation.  Even if it did, that wouldn't dictate how others should write it. (Other newspapers don't follow the Times's preferences even when writing about the Times.)

Comment: Doesn't my initial comment prove the case that capitalising the first word in The Times  is pretty important in order to avoid possible misreadings?

Comment: That's a valid point of view, but it's clearly an area where practice varies.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m not aware of the existence of a _Times_ magazine? Have you perhaps confused it with _Time_ magazine?

Comment: @MikeScott Yes, you're right. I slipped up.

Comment: Note that we sometimes make fun of titles that include “The”, such as by referring the *The New York Times*, because it sounds a bit pretentious.

Answer (score -1):

You should keep it as a small letter.

There is no such rule to use upper case to the 'the'.

Comment: Please give a little more clarification, along the lines of explaining why that’s true, whether it’s so in all similar cases, etc.

Comment: @Fivesideddice general, there is no rule to use upper case to the 'the'

Comment: Please quote your source(s).

Comment: @AndrzejSydor well, yes, but if it’s a title, a case might be made that you should.

Comment: What about when it's part of a name, like **[The Guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardian)**?

Comment: @Davo it's just a newspaper name. It's not a rule it's just a name created by someone to emphasize the name.

Comment: The rule is that names are capitalized, and if "The" is part of the name, then that "The" is capitalized. Your answer is misleading if exceptions are not noted.

Comment: @Davo - from their website suggesting a daily email: "All the day’s headlines and highlights from **the Guardian**, direct to you every morning". Wikipedia pages are notoriously unreliable or out-of-date.

Comment: Fair enough - let's use [The Gap](https://queenslandplaces.com.au/the-gap) in Queensland as an example, then.